# Example of OAuth authenticated request using .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, api, authentication, oauth

The Node.JS code below sends 0-legged OAuth authenticated request to the API:

```
'use strict';
var OAuth = require('OAuth');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var oauth = new OAuth.OAuth(
  'http://example.com/oauth/request_token',
  'http://example.com/oauth/access_token',
  'mykey',
  'none',
  '1.0',
  null,
  'HMAC-SHA1'
);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  oauth.get(
    'http://example.com/api',
    'token123',
    'tokensecret123',
    function (error, data, response){
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      res.json(data);
    });
});
```

I need to convert this code to C# or VB.NET. Any sample of OAuth authenticated request in .Net will help too.

Comment: This is very simple in node because you have a library `require('OAuth')` that you're pulling in that makes it simple. Doing this in .NET is going to require some effort to find a library that will allow you to do the same thing, and probably with a lot more code. If there exists a .NET library that will let you do this in what is basically 10 lines of code, I want to know what it is!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Guillaume Sasdy for steering me towards RestSharp. Here is a working solution that works the same way as the node.js code in my question. 
Since API I'm accessing is using 0-legged OAuth, the Access Token and Access Secret are known upfront and make things much easier.

```
const string consumerKey = "mykey";
const string consumerSecret = "none";
var baseUrl = "https://example.com";
var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);

var request = new RestRequest("/api");
client.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(
    consumerKey, consumerSecret, "token123", "tokensecret123"
);

var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it with the library [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) which helps to deal with REST API.

The code below send a request to get a token from the OAuth:

```
var restClient = new RestClient();
restClient.BaseUrl = new Uri("theApiBaseUrl");

string encodedCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"yourAppId:yourSecret"));

// change the request below per the API requirement
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("theApiUrlForAuthentication", Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Basic {encodedCredentials}");
request.AddQueryParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
request.AddQueryParameter("scope", "api");

IRestResponse response = restClient.Execute(request);

// the token should be in the JSON string response.Content
// now you'll want to deserialize the JSON to get the token
var jsonWithToken = MyFunctionToGetToken(response.Content);
```

Now you have the token in order to do **authenticated calls** to the API:

```
var restClient = new RestClient();
restClient.BaseUrl = new Uri("theApiBaseUrl");

RestRequest request = new RestRequest("theApiEndpoint", Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/hal+json");
request.AddHeader("profile", "https://api.slimpay.net/alps/v1");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");

RestClient.Execute(request);
```

Each API is different, so you'll surely have to modify my code (add or remove headers, encoding the credentials, ...) so that it works for you.